# Check if db exist before displaying any page

Tags: flutter

I want to check if local db is null or not before displaying any page.

I implemented a code in database helper class:

```
Future checkDb() async{
      var db = await getDatabasesPath();
      var dbPath = join(db,"main.db");
      bool exist = await databaseExists(dbPath);
      return exist;
  }

Future<Database> get db async{
    if(_db!= null)
    {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initdb();
    return _db;
  }

  initdb() async{
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path,"main.db");
    var ourDb = await openDatabase(path,version:1,onCreate:_onCreate);
    return ourDb;

  }

  void _onCreate(Database db,int version)async {
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE User("
          "userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          "first_name TEXT,"
          "last_name TEXT,"
          "user_password TEXT,"
          ")");
    print("User Table created");
    
  }
  //insertion of data
  Future<int> saveUser(User user)async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.insert("User", user.tMap());
    return res;
  }
```

If this returns false i want to navigate the page to signIn page. I implemented this in main.dart:

```
Future<void> main()async(){
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
AcadFlip myApp;
if(db.checkDb() ){
       myApp = AcadFlip(
      initialRoute: '/SignIn');
    }
return runApp(myApp);
}

class AcadFlip extends StatelessWidget {

  final String initialRoute;

  AcadFlip({this.initialRoute});
    
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        initialRoute:initialRoute,
        routes: routes,
    );
  }
}
```

How to make the function checkdb() display or return boolean rather than `Future<dynamic>` instance for the navigation?

Comment: since your data is a Future your gonna have to wait for some time though, its asynchronous process but you can show a loading process or another placeholder before it finishes processing and as soon as it is completed you can change the page

Comment: Adding to @Henok you have to use a `FutureBuilder` if you want to use that in the `build`method. It's a `Future` so you have to `await` or `.then` it to obtain the value when it's available. So in your main method you should add `await` before `db.checkDb()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `db.checkDb()` is a Future so to get the bool value and use it inside the if you should rewrite it like `if(await db.checkDb())`. That said a good approach woul be to change it like this

```
Future<void> main()async(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
  bool exist = await db.checkDb();
  return runApp(AcadFlip(initialRoute: exist ? '/' : '/SignIn')); //or whatever your initial route is if it exists
}
```

That way it checks the future value, and after that if it exists it uses the initial route '/', if it doesn't it uses '/SignIn'. With your previous code the if never run because it wanted a boolean value, and even if you use await it will only enter if its true, if not `AcadFlip myApp` will never initialize and you will try to run a null object `runApp(null)`

**UPDATE**

Your initdb method uses `Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` while your checkDb uses `await getDatabasesPath();` so you're using a different path to check if the db exists there.

```
Future checkDb() async{
  Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() //use the same path as initdb
  var dbPath = join(documentDirectory.path,"main.db");
  bool exist = await databaseExists(dbPath);
  return exist;
}
```

Or you can use getDatabasesPath in both checkDb and initdb, the only thing to rememeber is using the same path in both so the logic works

`getDatabasesPath` is a function of `sqflite` that returns a default path used to create a db depending of the platform using (Android or IOS). `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` is a path from `path_provider` but it will not return the same path that getDatabasesPath

Comment: Why does it return false even after restarting the app? @EdwynZN

Comment: I would need to see more of how you open and close your db to understand why is always returning false (never exists?)

Comment: You're using different paths in initdb and checkDb, that's why it always return false